# How to set minimum purchase order amount

Tags: magento, orders

When customer places an order, how to set minimum order amount?

i.e) Total amount of order not below than $500.

I know how to get total order amount. But I don't know where to place that code and where to check

```
   sOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
   $oOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($sOrderId);
    if($oOrder >=$500)
    {
   .....
     }
```

If customer has purchased total less than $500, they won't allow to checkout at the cart.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Login as admin, then go to **System->configuration**, then select **‘Sales‘** from left Nav and click on **‘Minimum order amount‘.**
Then select Yes from Enable dropdown, enter Minimum order amount, enter message and also enter error message that will be shown whenever the order will be less than specified amount at the shopping cart.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the scope of the minimum amount setting. For that you need a new module with a `system.xml` file that contains the same path to the minimum amount field and just changes the `<show_in_store>` value. Read more about this [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/9855/146).