# Minimum ReOrder Amount, how can I fix this?

Tags: magento

Here's the scenario.

For first time order, the minimum amount needs to be more that $1000 in order to check out.

When customer wants to reorder, the minimum amount needs to be more than $500 in order to checkout.

In each time, it allowed order which have more than $1000 only

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: you'll need some code to do this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this you could rewrite `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote`

```
 /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php

public function validateMinimumAmount($multishipping = false)
{
    $storeId = $this->getStoreId();
    $minOrderActive = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('sales/minimum_order/active', $storeId);
    $minOrderMulti  = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('sales/minimum_order/multi_address', $storeId);
    $minAmount      = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/amount', $storeId);

    if (!$minOrderActive) {
        return true;
    }

    if(previous order exist and $baseTotal > 500){
        return true;
    }

    ....
```

Comment: thank for your response, How to check that customer already purchased or not?

Answer (score 0):

You could also disable [How to set minimum purchase order amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017866/how-to-set-minimum-purchase-order-amount).

Then implement your own logic see [Magento Maximum Allowed Order Amount](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-maximum-allowed-order-amount/)

```
class Inchoo_MaxOrderAmount_Model_Observer
{
    private $_helper;

    public function __construct()
    {
    $this->_helper = Mage::helper('inchoo_maxorderamount');
    }

    public function enforceSingleOrderLimit($observer)
    {
        if (!$this->_helper->isModuleEnabled()) {
            return;
        }
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        /*
         check to see if order greater than minimum amount 
         or has a previous and current amount > 500
        */
        if ((float)$quote->getGrandTotal() < (float)$this->_helper->getSingleOrderMinAmount() || (has Previous Order && $quote->getGrandTotal() > 500)) {
            $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($this->_helper->getSingleOrderTopAmount(), true, false);
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError(
            $this->_helper->__($this->_helper->getSingleOrderTopAmountMsg(), $formattedPrice));
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart'));
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```